# Problems with playing sound in Android using SoundPool

Tags: android, audio, soundpool, android-audiomanager

In my Android game, I am playing short sound effects using AudioManager and SoundPool.

While this works fine on Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1, when I ported the game to Samsung Galaxy SIII, I am experiencing strange lock-ups of the screen and crashes of the application with re-booting of the phone, when I am trying to play the sound from the SoundPool.

It behaves quite erratically and one of 4 things happen (in no particular order):

(1) Application starts as normal and all sounds play normally.

(2) Application crashes completely and mobile reboots.

(3) Application freezes shortly (3-5 seconds) upon trying to play the sound, then continues normally, but sounds don't work.

(4) Application starts as normal, but none of the sounds plays. *

- There is a strange twist to the 4th case. None of the sounds plays, but when I activate game background music (which plays via MediaPlayer, not via AudioManager/SoundPool) this somehow 'flushes down' the stuck sound effects which should play at the beginning of the game, and now they all catch-up and play at once. This 'flushing down' somehow returns everything back to normal and from this point on all the sound effects from the SoundPool play normally, as they should.

The error which I am getting is:

AudioTrack: obtainBuffer timed out (is the CPU pegged?) "*CPU pegged*" what the hell does it even mean ???

Note that the problems happen at the point in the game when I am attempting to ***play*** the sounds from the soundpool by SoundPool.play, ***not when I am loading them*** by SoundPool.load.

I tried just about everything and now I am at the end of my wits. Did anybody have the same problem? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: "CPU pegged" is explained here: http://soledadpenades.com/2009/08/25/is-the-cpu-pegged-and-friends/

Comment: Yeah, I found that also, but that is not really an "explanation" is it... Also it does not give any suggestions on how to solve the problem.

Comment: I have spent on this problem now over a week, took the whole class apart, modified, changed parameters, removed bits which I thought could cause the problem... No improvement. Re-sampled all sounds to the lowest sampling rate possible... No improvement either.

I am getting really fed up with this problem and starting to think I might dump the whole unreliable SoundPool and replace it with some other way of playing sounds...

Does anybody have any suggestions as to what is the best and most reliable way of playing sounds in Android? (not music - short sound effects).

Comment: Have you tested on other devices too? Perhaps it's a bug of your Galaxy SIII? According to the SoundPool docu, it's intended exactly for the purpose of playing short sound-effects with low CPU usage.

Comment: Yes, that is strange, that is what I thought... but in fact it seems to completely overload the CPU. Yes, I have created this game originally on Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1, where it works just fine. Does anybody else have similar problems with SoundPool on Galaxy SIII ???